# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when parsing HTML

Tags: python, html, parsing

I have a test a program where I am trying to pull out all the text from each HTML tag. It seems to work until I override the `__init__` function.

I get the error:

```
 File "./html.py", line 9, in __init__
    TransParser.__init__(self)
  File "./html.py", line 9, in __init__
    TransParser.__init__(self)
  File "./html.py", line 9, in __init__
    TransParser.__init__(self)
  File "./html.py", line 9, in __init__
    TransParser.__init__(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The program is here:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

trans = {
'History': 'History TRANSLATED',
'Acknowledgements': 'Acknowledgements TRANSLATED'
}

inputHTML = """<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="section-title"><a href="/about%20/history">History</a>        </td>

        <td class="section-title"><a href="/about/team">Project Team</a></td>

        <td class="section-title"><a href="/about/data">Contributors of data</a></td>

        <td class="section-title"><a href=
        "/about/acknowledgements">Acknowledgements</a></td>

        <td class="section-title"><a href="/about/origins">African Origins
        Project</a></td>

        <td class="section-title"><a href="/about/contacts">Contact us</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="section-desc">A brief account of the origins of a single multi-source
        dataset of the trans-Atlantic slave trade and its realization first as a CD-ROM
        published by Cambridge University Press in 1999 and now, in an expanded version,
        on the Voyages website.</td>

        <td class="section-desc">Names of the principal investigators, of members of the
        project development team, and of individuals serving on the steering committee
        and advisory board.</td>

        <td class="section-desc">Names of scholars and researchers whose findings on the
       trans-Atlantic slave trade have been incorporated into the Voyages Database.</td>

        <td class="section-desc">Major sponsors and institutional partners of the Voyages
        website, as well as other organizations and individuals who have assisted the
        work of the project team.</td>

        <td class="section-desc">A scholar-public collaborative project using audio
        recordings of names in African Names Database to trace the geographic origins of
         Africans transported in the transatlantic slave trade.</td>

        <td class="section-desc">Members of the Voyages editorial board and the email
         address for contacting the website.</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>"""


class TransParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        TransParser.__init__(self)
        self.trans_data = self.rawdata

    def handle_data(self, data):
         data = data.strip()
        if data:
            section = trans.get(data, data)
            #self.trans_data = self.trans_data.replace(data, section)

parser = TransParser()
parser.feed(inputHTML)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TransParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        TransParser.__init__(self)
        #         ^^^ You are calling the same constructor recursively.
```

**Fix**:

```
class TransParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        ..
        ..
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class TransParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        TransParser.__init__(self)
        self.trans_data = self.rawdata
```

What are you trying to do here?  The **init** method calls itself; this is infinite recursion.  Do you mean to call the parent's **init** method, perhaps?  That would be

```
        super().__init__(self)
```